# How can i get the data next in table users on firebase?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get the next child after user without any triggers?

```
 FirebaseResponse resp2 = await client.GetTaskAsync("user/");
 Data obj2 = resp2.ResultAs<Data>();
```

[image: How to get the data of Amiel,Ernesto,Jonneth]

Comment: How can i get the data of Amiel,Ernesto,Jonneth

Comment: Without hard coding it

Comment: Are you trying to iterate through your data?

Comment: im trying to retrieve the data to my datagridview.

Comment: Im trying to get the NAME before the value

Comment: i mean the child of the "user"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [Fire#](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp), you can listen to `child_added` events to retrieve data from the server. This will work it's way through your database until you tell it to stop.

```
EventStreamResponse response = await client.OnAsync("user", (sender, args) => {
       System.Console.WriteLine(args.Path);
       System.Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
});

// Call dispose to stop listening for events
// response.Dispose();
```

Comment: I am using fire# but there is no EventStreamResponse.

Comment: can't also use the client.OnAsync

Comment: This is taken directly from the [Fire# docs](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp#listen-streaming-from-the-rest-api) and `EventStreamResponse` is part of Fire# at `FireSharp.Core.Response.EventStreamResponse`. Regarding "can't use client.OnAsync" - why not?

Comment: sorry my fire# is out dated. still got a problem in sender

Comment: try
            {
                EventStreamResponse response = await client.OnAsync("account", (SendKeys, args, context) =>
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(args.Path);
                    System.Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
                });
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

Comment: That's a null error. Follow these [steps here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660186) to help figure it out. If I were to take a stab in the dark, I'd say you haven't [initialized the `client` object](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp#how-can-i-configure-firesharp) properly. Solving the issue beyond this point will be up to you.